# How to compile a native library using NDK build system from outside an app project?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm trying to compile a native lib using ndk tools outside of any project.
I am using the following at the terminal:

```
ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=. APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=./Android.mk APP_PLATFORM=android-9  V=1
```

I also have at the same directory of Android.mk an Application.mk

```
APP_BUILD_SCRIPT := $(call my-dir)/Android.mk
NDK_PROJECT_PATH := $(call my-dir)
APP_PLATFORM := android-9
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
```

I would like to use instead of passing those flags from the command line. The build system is ignoring my Application.mk though. What am I doing wrong? Or else might what I'm trying to do (compiling a library from outside of an app project) not be possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compiling a library from outside of an application project is possible.

You just missed setting `NDK_APPLICATION_MK` to your Application.mk file.

```
ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=. NDK_APPLICATION_MK=Application.mk APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=Android.mk
```

A simpler way to do that is to put the make files(Android.mk, Application.mk) in a folder named `jni/` that what the build system expects to find them. And you will just call `ndk-build` on the project root folder to build your library.